# Adding a glyphicon to a control through c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, replace, glyphicons

```
Dim glyph As HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
glyph = New HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
glyph.InnerHtml = "<span class=""glyphicons glyphicons-restart""></span> Reset"
btnBarButtonBar.SummaryButton.Controls.Add(glyph)
```

I currently am doing it through VB like this but could anybody convert this for me to C# please? I just need to replace the current summary button which is built through the framework and directs the user to another page and replace it with this button which resets all values to blank. I have the .asp pages working already using the above code, I now need to convert to so it works in aspx/c#

Comment: For future reference, there are many online tools for automatically converting C# to VB.NET, and back.  Here is just one example, just paste the code in to the textbox and hit "Convert". http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, this will come in handy, I wasn't aware of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var glyph = new HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl();
glyph.InnerHtml = "<span class=\"glyphicons glyphicons-restart\"></span> Reset";
btnBarButtonBar.SummaryButton.Controls.Add(glyph);
```